# Coloring points in a pairs plot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to color points in a pairs plot based of certain row indexes. Here is the code I used for plotting 1 variable against another.

```
cases<-which(rownames(data_no_na) %in% colnames(tumor_data))
controls<-which(rownames(data_no_na) %in% colnames(control_data))

plot(y=range(pca[,1]),x=range(pca[,2]),type='n',xlab="Principle Component 2",ylab="Principle Component 1", main="Iterative Thresholding Sparse PCA")

points(y=pca[cases,1], x=pca[cases,2], col = 'red' )
points(y=pca[controls,1], x=pca[controls,2], col = 'blue' );
```

A simple pairs plot is something like:

```
pairs(pca[,1:3])
```

EDIT: EXAMPLE:

```
cases<-1:10
controls<-11:20

pca<-matrix(c(rnorm(3*10,0,1),rnorm(3*10,5,1)),nrow=20,ncol=3)
```

Comment: You should give a reproducible example.

Comment: Which means we need to see the output of either your real data or some dummy data which can illustrate the plot above. Try pasting the output of  `dput( head( cases ) )` &  `dput( head( controls ) )` if your data does not contain many many columns.

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible by having a look at [**How to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for us to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I put up a reproducible example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something like this?

```
cols <- character(nrow(iris))
cols[] <- "black"

cols[iris$Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor")] <- "blue"
cols[iris$Species == "virginica"] <- "red"
pairs(iris,col=cols)
```

Comment: Yes, you can do the same for shapes.

Comment: For the ones considering to use a continuous variable for the coloring of the points: remember to sort/arrange your entire data.frame by that variable before feeding it to `pairs`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if @Roland 's answer works in some version, but at least in my Windows R 3.4.2, it doesn't.

The function pairs takes [many arguments](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.4.3/topics/pairs). Some of this are used to indicate what function to map to the diagonal, upper and lower panels. By default, it uses the plot (points) function.

This function has a parameter `bg` used to specify the fill color of markers that take it, like `pch = 21`.

Also, the color mapping can be done much more efficiently with unclass. For example, with a two-levels factor variable:

```
colors <- c('black', 'red')[unclass(factor_variable)]
```

Then, this does the magic:

```
pairs(data, bg=colors)
```

Comment: colors <- c('black', 'red')[unclass(factor_variable)] is a good option. But using bg=colors, did not allocate the colors to markers, col=colors did. I was using pch=19